# How to prevent openjdk-6-jre-headless from clobbering Oracle JDK installation?

Tags: installation, apt, java, openjdk, update-alternatives

My automated build server runs a job that depends on [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). The script invokes `apt-get install ant`. Ant depends on `openjdk-6-jre-headless` which runs `update-alternatives` making itself the default JDK (rewriting my symbolic links in the process). I already had Oracle JDK (manually) installed and do not wish `update-alternatives` to be run. I cannot manually restore `update-alternatives` every time this happens.

Someone tried to have this corrected last year but was shot down: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678195

How do I prevent `openjdk-6-jre-headless` from invoking `update-alternatives` or, worse case scenarion, how do I look up the value before the installation process and restore it after-the-fact?

**UPDATE**: I filed a new bug report [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1223623). I would appreciate your support.

Answer (score 11):

Answering my own question:

I used https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/23678 to install Oracle JDK. As you can see, these instructions invoke `update-alternatives` with a priority of 1. When `openjdk-6-jre-headless` installs itself it sets a priority of 1061 (where a higher priority replaces lower ones).

In order to fix this problem I simply gave Oracle JDK a priority higher than 1061. When `openjdk-6-jre-headless` installed itself, it no longer clobbered Oracle JDK as the default.

**UPDATE**: To update OpenJDK's priorities I simply re-ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java" 2000
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javac" 2000
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaws" 2000
```

with a priority of 2000 instead of 1 (the priority is the last command-line argument).

Comment: @Braiam, I've updated the answer.

Comment: On my system, the Oracle JDK was installed at /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80 and the executables were in the bin directory beneath that.